# Edit Pentaho User Console homepage

Tags: pentaho

I need to edit the homepage in Pentaho user console. I want to change it to my own design. However, I don't know how to change it. Can someone guide me to do this?

I'm totally a beginner in using pentaho. I also not really good in Java. I use Pentaho Enterprise Edition.

Comment: I think you should really check out this thread..
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29364420/2351586

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [page](http://www.prashantraju.com/2010/02/customising-the-pentaho-user-console-part-2/)

it explains how to do Customising Login Dialog Messages, Customising User Console Messages, productName, loadingConsole, etc

Comment: Do you have any other tutorial page that you can suggest for me to take a look? I need to edit the homepage(Page after login). I need to change it to other design.