# How to change Pentaho after login page

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

After login to Pentaho BI server as a user, the Pentaho shows a default page.

I need to redesign that page to match look at feel of a company website. What files do I need to edit and how to give links from that page to dashboards in Pentaho?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of redesigning the Pentaho screens create a "central  dashboard" with links to all of your "sub-dashboards". This central place can be created as an another Pentaho CDE dashboard and you can make it look and feel as company website, because you can attach any HTML, CSS, JavaScript code and image files to the dashboard. You don't need to use any `component` (chart, etc.) or `datasource`. Just edit the `layout` of the dashboard.

So, the `central dashboard` will be accessible on e.g.:

`http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:home:CentralDashboard.wcdf/generatedContent`

When a user navigates to the above URL (he did not used `Pentaho Login Screen` to log in = `http://localhost:8080/pentaho/Home`), he is prompted to log in by a dialog. He fills the dialog, logs in and see the `central dashboard`. So provide the user only a link to `central dashboard` instead of `Pentaho Login Screen`.

When you create a `central dashboard` you need to have a links to your sub-dashboards. To get the `links` navigate through the `Browse Files` in Pentaho  to a particular dashboard, click on CDE file of the dashboard and choose **Open in a new window** to open the dashboard. This opens the dashboard in a new browser window. So you can **copy the URL** of it and then paste this link to the `central dashboard`.

This way users do not need to use the **Pentaho Login screen** but they directly access the `central dashboard` page where they choose concrete sub-dashboard they want to work with.

Comment: Not necessarily the answer I was looking for. Problem with this approach is that I lose the folder/files security that comes with Pentaho. I would like to create user groups and users in each group. Create dashboards in folders and map folder to user group. With your approach that would not be possible.

Comment: I think it is possible. I use exactly the same as you mentioned. One folder = one user group. Than I have a `central dashboard` where depending on which user (from which user group) is logged in the appropriate content is shown. The important thing is - you need to know how to obtain the information about `user group` of a logged user. Use this JavaScript code: `Dashboards.context.roles` (e.g. ["Administrator", "Authenticated"]) or `Dashboards.context.user` (e.g. "admin"). Then you need to manupilate a DOM using JavaScript code to show/hide page elements accoring to `user group`.

Comment: Ah! With this approach you are re creating what is already built in Pentaho. I would still want to see if we can change HTML/CSS of "Browse Files" page (../tomcat/webapps/pentaho/mantle/browser/index.jsp). This is  a real requirement and we can work together off line if you are up to it. Let me know.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It depends on what the users need. Our user only care about accessing dashboards from one central point, they don't use any other Pentaho features, only admin does. So far, I didn't need to change any JSP page, but it is possible - the code is there and can be customized.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's the version of Pentaho BI server you are using.

In my case with Pentaho 5.3

- If you want to change the login page, just modify the jsp file under `biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/jsp/PUCLogin.jsp`
- If you want to change the home page after login, just modify this jsp file `biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/mantle/Mantle.jsp`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the example above, but I wouldnt necessarily re-implement the login process (as you could well introduce security flaws etc). I would instead use CST - Community Startup Tabs - that does exactly what you're asking for.

Details here: http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/cst/

Comment: To be honest. I have not discovered CST yet.

Comment: That was why i suggested it :)

Answer (score 0):

The default page bi server is showing is located in:
`biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/mantle/home/content/welcome/index.html`.

You can modify it as your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For Pentaho Server Enterprise Edition version 9.5:

Reading the code in PUCLogin.jsp gave me a few hints (Thanks, Max Peng!), and eventually I discovered that the real solution is to edit the file .../pentaho-solutions/system/pentaho.xml and change:

<login-show-sample-users-hint>true</login-show-sample-users-hint>

into

<login-show-sample-users-hint>false</login-show-sample-users-hint>